# c# Is there a cleaner way setting the same flag boolean variable to true within multiple if statements

Tags: c#

I have an example like this and I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to assign true to the same variable.  The if statements are only for example purposes.  The question is not about the if statements but just trying to find a cleaner way to do this rather than submitting the same flag to true over and over.

```
public static bool CheckForCondition(DateTime a, DateTime b, bool conditionFlag)
{
     if (a > b)
     {
          conditionFlag = true;
     }
     else if (b < a)
     {
          conditionFlag = true;
     }
     else if (a == b)
     {
          conditionFlag = true;
     }

     return conditionFlag;
}
```

My goal was to avoid the repetition of the same code and make it cleaner if possible.

Comment: You could of course simply set `conditionFlag = a > b || b < a || a == b;`  But whether that's actually an improvement is subjective.

Comment: you would get better answers with a more concrete example

Comment: You can set "conditionFlag " to true by default at the top, then only flip it to false when the "opposite" conditions occurs. Could be less code, but without a CONCRETE example as pm100 mentioned already, this question is pointless...

Comment: Perhaps `bool CheckForCondition(DateTime a, DateTime b) => !(a < b);`

Comment: You could just do `return conditionFlag || a >= b;`

Comment: @pm100 I disagree

Comment: LOL at @CaiusJard for playing Roblox! Wait...I do the same thing. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fine:

```
public static bool CheckForCondition(DateTime a, DateTime b, bool conditionFlag) 
  => conditionFlag || a >= b;
```

You accept a bool and overwrite it to `true` if `a` is `>= b`. Because you never set it to `false` it means it's effectively an OR operation.. The only way you get a `false` out is if it's a `false` in and `b > a`.

Comment: I love these ones, I should hand them out at interviews

Comment: The if logic can be anything it's not part of the question really but I definitely like the idea of combining the condition flag and the condition.  Doing it this way if it was basic if conditions and just setting the flag I could eliminate the if's all together.

Answer (score 2):

The first 2 if statements are basically the same thing you do not need to check both, you could also use greater than or equal to condition to combine the first and third if statements.

```
conditionFlag = false    
if (a >= b)
{
    conditionFlag = true;
}

return conditionFlag;
```

Edit: This assumes that you want the function to return false if none of the conditions are true, otherwise Caius Jard's answer is better. Can also be simplified even more as mentioned by Matthew Watson in the comments.

Comment: Or just `return a >= b;`

Comment: @MatthewWatson I thought that, but then revised it because I realized it's subtly different

Comment: You're right - so you could just do `return conditionFlag || a >= b;`

Comment: @pm100 it's not `a<b` it's `b<a` which is equal to `a>b`

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer ignores that the flag was passed into the function.  This would override the flag's value and would not work.

Comment: @Mike This is why I added the edit to point out the assumption and to recommend another answer.